# PHP gd imagettftext() height

Tags: php, image, gd

Is there a way to get PHP [`imagettftext()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) font height?

I know that we can get width by [`imagettfbbox()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php). Can we get the height too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you evidently can simply be looking at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php). Scroll down and use your browsers find function to search for the following:

```
jodybrabec at gmail dot com
```

Below his name he provides a nice cusotm function for you to use.
(got a link actually right here, no need to use the find function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php#105593)

Comment: so if i want to center it in background its will be like this ?

Comment: (bgheight /2) - (ttfheight /2) ?

Comment: You could probably say:

`$x = (.5 * imagesx($im))+(.5 * $txtWidth);`

Where $im is your image resource and $txtWidth is the width of the text that you want to center.